# Retrieve values from a column in order of appearance and priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are 5 picklist values that can be stored in a column including `NULL`

I want to return values if they appear in a priority order such as:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.whatever    
WHERE ColumnName = 'Value X'
```

(If this value isn't present, I want to ask for the next value in my priority (Value W, Value Z, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by that priority list and only take the first entry using `top 1`

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM dbo.whatever
order by case when ColumnName = 'Value X' then 1
              when ColumnName = 'Value Y' then 2
              when ColumnName = 'Value Z' then 3
              else 4
         end
```